# Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.AutorecoveringModel'

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, message

I'm starting to learn RabbitMq and use it with my C# code, but it's giving this error:
(Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.AutorecoveringModel'.)

[image: Exception that is occurring]

I was trying to consume from Rabbit QUEUE and convert to right Task object, but when she goes to ack he gives except and loses the value.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem when I was using the 'using' statement to create the rabbitmq connection and channel.

I stopped using it because I needed to keep the channel open for the entire lifetime object.
Note: I created a function to dispose the connection and channel when finished.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, This issue has occurred to me when I was debugging the code. For me it looks like the event remains open for few seconds or may be milliseconds. try having the debug pointer after the `BasicAck` function. it should work.
It also implies that somewhere in the Event consumer configuration you can increase the timing... that is still to explore. Basically during the code debugging event object disposes in after few seconds.